# Odoo - Search module for show group by parent / child value in tree view

Tags: python, module, odoo

I'm looking for a module like https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/16.0/app_web_widget_ztree/ but for tree structure when grouped by category. I want when I select the parent it shows the first children first and when I select a child it shows the subchild and so on.

Currently Odoo displays everything with names like parent/child/subchild.

THANKS